# Groovy script works in console but not in job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

So I've created a Groovy script, and it works in the console. I then implemented it into my job in the field `Execute Groovy Script` but then it failed.

Here I have the console, and I do know the imports aren't needed, but I had to try.

[image: console]

But When I run my job with this code, I get this error:

```
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Buildsl (hant) in workspace C:\JS\workspace\node_checker
[Vetus_node_checker] $ groovy C:\JS\workspace\node_checker\hudson633049885410603886.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson633049885410603886
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson633049885410603886
    at hudson633049885410603886.run(hudson633049885410603886.groovy:6)
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please include how you configured the groovy execution in your job.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are using the "Execute Groovy script", but to execute scripts like in Script Console you must use the "Execute *system* Groovy script" step.

[image]

The normal execute will start a new Java/JVM with Groovy which is not "connected" to your Jenkins.

Only the system step will execute the script *within* the existing Java/JVM that is running Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

So yes I had to run it as a `Execute system Groovy script`, but I also had to give the full path to the lib I'm using, before it worked. the `Script Console` didn't need the `jenkins.model...` part, but the job does.

[image: libs]